# Keyset pagination in Ef core 7

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pagination, keyset-pagination

i have been reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/ef/core/querying/pagination from EFCore team tried to implement it. The problem i am facing with is the example shown here is using a primary key of type INT. in my entity class given below the primary is of type GUID

```
public sealed class Company{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; } = null!;
    public string Email { get; private set; } = null!;
    public string? ContactNumber { get; private set; }
    public string? Address { get; private set; }
    public string QBAccount { get; private set; } = null!;
    public string BoxFolderPath { get; private set; } = null!;
}
```

i tried to implement this with the same condition where given in the example in the link which is to compare the pk in the `Where()` clause as

```
var lastId = Guid.Parse("42ce0165-62b8-4ef6-f62f-08dadc0d2e5d");
var nextPage = context.Posts
    .OrderBy(b => b.PostId)
    .Where(b => b.PostId > lastId)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

but i dont get the expected pagination result. any help please

Comment: Real implementation is complex. You have to understand that `OrderBy` values has to be unique key. Also how do you plan to return cursor to the frontend? How to serialize.

Comment: This page in docs makes it seem that sorting by Guid doesn't really work correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/comparing-guid-and-uniqueidentifier-values

Comment: i have found this https://github.com/mrahhal/MR.EntityFrameworkCore.KeysetPagination, it has tests for paging based on guid. but, its not very clear. the examples are not available.

Comment: Haven't tested it myself, but maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920200/entity-framework-core-guid-greater-than-for-paging

Answer (score 0):

You're ordering by a Guid, which are not sequential by default. There are ways to generate sequential guids, but I'm not sure that would fix your ordering in a reliable way.

I believe it is better to order by another property that represents your data in an orderly fashion. I see you have a `CreatedOn` property. When you would order by that property, you should get the same kind of results as ordering by an integer ID property.

It could introduce new kind of problems, your `.Where` clause will be different. It could change to the last `CreatedOn` value or you can create a subquery to retrieve the `CreatedOn` value of the `lastId` record.

Comment: CreatedOn will never change in my context, i have cleared other properties such as updatedOn and deletedOn for brevity. so i feel createdOn is a better option i guess.

Comment: @thanzeel please let us know if this solution worked out for you!

Comment: i tried, bu it did not work as expected